# VM2022:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, ajax

I send a GET request from the back end to get the json response. I got this error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
>           at DOMEval (jquery-3.3.1.js:111)
>           at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.3.1.js:345)
>           at text script (jquery-3.3.1.js:9640)
>           at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.3.1.js:8787)
>           at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9255)
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)

[image]

My AJAX request code is:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET", //rest Type
  dataType: 'jsonp', //mispelled
  url: "{{ url_for('live') }}",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.counters.length; i++) {
      var counter = msg.counters[i];
      console.log(counter);
    }
  }, 
  error: ErrorMsg
});
```

I have no idea where I went wrong. please help.

Comment: `msg` is already an object so decoding it again will cause the error you see. You just need to remove the `var msg = JSON.decode(msg);` line

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan still getting the error

Comment: Is it the same error?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes same error. VM2335:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Are you sure the response is JSONP? It's not 'misspelled', as it's a completely different format to JSON. Try changing to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes that's the problem thank you.  Resolved.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added an answer for you below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues. Firstly the response will already be deserialised for you buy jQuery. Deserialising it again will cause the error you see. Secondly, the response format appears to be JSON, not JSONP, so the `dataType` property needs to be amended as well. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: "{{ url_for('live') }}",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (msg) {
    for (var i = 0; i < msg.counters.length; i++) {
      var counter = msg.counters[i];
      console.log(counter);
    }
  }, 
  error: ErrorMsg
});
```

Comment: I was searching for the exact issue and finally found here, I never loose my trust on stackoverflow :P